# Symfony2 Form make one field required true between 2 fields

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I have a entity of seats allocation to institute, there are 3 fields, total seats, male seats, female seats. the scenario is either all seats are for male or female or it can be divided among the male and female.

In definitive, my problem is : I want to check the user choose at least one of the two fields required (maleSeat and femaleSeat)

```
 ->add('maxSeats', 'integer', array(
                'label' => ucwords('max Seats'),
                'required' => true, // Choose if it's required or not
                'constraints' => $constraints['maxSeats'],
                'invalid_message' => 'You entered an invalid value, it should include %num%',
                'sonata_help' => 'Here some help text!!!',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control',
                    'help' => 'My Help Message',
                ),
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'control-label'
                )
            ))
            ->add('maleSeats', 'integer', array(
                'label' => ucwords('male Seats'),
                'required' => true, // Choose if it's required or not
                'constraints' => $constraints['maleSeats'],
                'invalid_message' => 'You entered an invalid value, it should include %num%',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'control-label'
                )
            ))
            ->add('femaleSeats', 'integer', array(
                'label' => ucwords('female Seats'),
                'required' => true, // Choose if it's required or not
                'constraints' => $constraints['femaleSeats'],
                'invalid_message' => 'You entered an invalid value, it should include %num%',
                'attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'form-control'
                ),
                'label_attr' => array(
                    'class' => 'control-label'
                )
            ))

$constraints = array(
            'maxSeats' => array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Range(array(
                    'min'        => 1,
                    'minMessage' => 'Min Seats is 1'
                )),
                new Assert\Regex(array(
                    'pattern' => '/[0-9]/',
                    'message' => 'Total Seats Should Only be a Positive Number',
                )),
            ),
            'maleSeats' => array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Range(array(
                    'min'        => 1,
                    'minMessage' => 'Min Seats is 1'
                )),
                new Assert\Length(array(
                    'min' => 1,
                    'max' => 30,
                    'minMessage' => 'The min Seats must be more than 6 and less than 1 characters long',
                    'maxMessage' => 'The min Seats must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long',
                )),
                new Assert\Regex(array(
                    'pattern' => '/[0-9]/',
                    'message' => 'Total Seats Should Only be a Positive Number',
                )),
            ),
            'femaleSeats' => array(
                new Assert\NotBlank(),
                new Assert\Range(array(
                    'min'        => 1,
                    'minMessage' => 'Min Seats is 1'
                )),
                new Assert\Length(array(
                    'min' => 1,
                    'max' => 30,
                    'minMessage' => 'The min Seats must be more than 6 and less than 1 characters long',
                    'maxMessage' => 'The min Seats must be more than 6 and less than 30 characters long',
                )),
                new Assert\Regex(array(
                    'pattern' => '/[0-9]/',
                    'message' => 'Total Seats Should Only be a Positive Number',
                )),
            ),

        );
```

I know it can be handled via jquery stuff but i don't wanted to involve jquery and other stuff here, how can i achieve this using symfony builtin components.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using a callback in your `Seat` entity :

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Context\ExecutionContextInterface;
// if you're using the older 2.4 validation API, you'll need this instead
// use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContextInterface;

class Seat
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->getFemaleSeats() == 0 && $this->getMaleSeats == 0) {
            // If you're using the new 2.5 validation API (you probably are!)
            $context->buildViolation('Female and male seat could not be empty at the same time')
                    ->atPath('maleSeats')
                    ->addViolation();
            // If you're using the old 2.4 validation API
            /*
            $context->addViolationAt(
                'maleSeats',
                'Female and male seat could not be empty at the same time'
            );
            */
        }

}
```

If you want more information on the configuration, I drop to you the link of the [symfony callback doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)